# Filter capacitors to avoid pop when hitting footswitch

Tags: capacitor, audio, passive-filter

This is an audio circuit question.

I have two line level signals going into two DIs going into a PA.

I want to craft a custom passive mute switch, sometimes when debugging feedback when performing live I have to unplug the line signals from my DIs. It would be **much** easier if I just had a button to act as a mute.

My circuit is just 2x 1/4" jacks in, 2x 1/4" jacks out, and a DPDT footswitch, simple as can be. When I press the footswitch, the output jacks are simply disconnected from the input jacks and left floating. The input jacks are connected to the two commons of the DPDT footswitch.

I would like to avoid a popping sound when hitting this footswitch though, as a loud pop can potentially blow PA gear.

So my thought was to have 2x capacitors inline with the two output jacks, since caps let AC through (the line level signal) but filter out DC.

Would this work? How do I chose a value? I was planning on just using a 22 nF, which seems like it can pass most audio frequencies without too much bass attenuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the pop sound might still be there since capacitors have leaking currents.  Put two resistor to the ground to make sure the DC level is the same on both sides when you turn on the switch.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpc2C0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 and R2 have the same value , pick one at least 10 times the output impedance.

To pass low frequencies (down to 10Hz) for 22uF choose R1, R2 at least 2K.

Answer (score -1):

Floating inputs to an audio amplifier are generally a bad idea as loud hum will be induced by stray pickup. The input signal should be grounded instead.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjdtwc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Alternative solution. R1 is optional.*

Do a simple test with your footswitch and wire it to short the output signal to ground.

R1 is optional if you are woried about overloading the output of the preceding stage.

R2 is optional. It will leak away any DC voltage on the line due to leakage on the output capacitors of the preceding stage or leakage on the input capacitors of the following stage.

Comment: The attenuation is lower and and it will get worse in time.  In time the switch will become noisy. Without R1 the output impedance will be closer to the SW impedance making things worse.